# Array not emptying

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im trying to empty the array below but it it just keeps piling onto it instead of actually emptying it.  Any ideas why this happens?

`displaytaken[];`

Edit: Adding a StackBlits:

Im getting way to confused. With the Snippet/JQ and im changing to much to get a accurate answer out of this.

Issue now is that it actually works in the stackblitz so something els is asstray will be editing it to reach a working recreation

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdec3f?

Another Edit:
Im finding it hard to recreate the issue but on the stacklits youll notice a function called checkinbetween() in there is a array called : `filteredArray`
This is storing data even if i clear it despite changing it from const to var  so its duplicating all outputs on my side

Screenshot to help show whats happening on my side:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As u can see I clear the array but then when I add to it again the old values are there still

Comment: Assigning a new empty array to the function parameter won't impact the outer variable, but setting the length to 0 should work. Could your provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I tried the normal way ofcourse of just settinng the orignal array length to 0 and i will do so

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Added snippet had to change something around, no idea why its complaining about my value when im just emptying it but thats about the same code i used

Comment: So when you pass an array into a function like in your previous example before the edit. The interpreter passes by value and not by reference. That is why it doesn't assign an empty array to the variable.

Comment: That makes complete sense. That function was silly to begin with I did however attempting the normal assignment way after the alert but the result is the same.. I think for some reason I thought if I pass it into the function then assign empty arrays then asign them back to the globals it would empty. ```Brain fart moment? ```

Comment: You haven't defined `value` in your snippet and naming your own function `alert()` will result in an infinite recursive loop. Please correct your snippet to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Typescript, which gives you the added advantages of using types. Also, I would advice you to start using immutablility.

Instead of populating some 'global' array, you should create functions for you that return you the data that you need:

```js
// Instead of this
const myDateArray: Date[] = [];
for (const someValue of someOtherDateArray) {
  if (some.condition()) {
    myDateArray.push(someValue);
  }
}

// Do this:
function getDateArray(otherDateArray: Date[]): Date[] {
  return otherDateArray.filter(date => some.condition());
}
```

That way, you don't *need* to clear the date array, as a new one can be requested on the fly.

To get to your answer, I assume you are looping over a lot of date arrays, and displaying them as taken dates in an `alert` box. here is how you can do that without clearing the array everytime:

```js
const allTakenDates = [
     [
        new Date('2018-01-16'),
        new Date('2018-03-26'),
        new Date('2018-05-22'),
        new Date('2018-12-01'),
        new Date('2018-01-23'),
    ],
     [
        new Date('2019-01-16'),
        new Date('2019-03-26'),
        new Date('2019-05-22'),
        new Date('2019-12-01'),
        new Date('2019-01-23'),
    ],
     [
        new Date('2020-01-16'),
        new Date('2020-03-26'),
        new Date('2020-05-22'),
        new Date('2020-12-01'),
        new Date('2020-01-23'),
    ]
];

function getDatesAsString(dates: Date[]): string[] {
    return dates.map(date => `${date.getFullYear()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}`);
}

for (const dates of allTakenDates) {
    
    const formattedDates = getDatesAsString(dates).join();
    alert('The following dates are taken: ' + formattedDates);
}
```

[And here is a working example of that code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQFTgawKZgCJyhiGAXhgG0AoGKqi6umMDAdxl3wAoByAJgAYBGABwBaAcP4A2TgEoANJXpVGLNhi58hogMzDuUuQsXLWeNTwEjeAVl3cZ8xUuYmO5zf26j+9w-WOr1Cy9dLR86AF0HOlpHf1NA-gBOYMkw2OcAt2TeHT00owz4rNEbbjsDRwZC1w1kjy98v2qzWuDuUIrqSN8yHuo4mt4+FP0ogpUivmGc3VG+pwnB6dLysabFlqHecU8BRroBzen+EMbw8nCAbnJyADMAVzBgKABLcBgAcwwoVQgAQQgAGUoAAnF5gD7sAAmpggAC4XBhSOFpAjoGCIciYABvXwg773EFgGAw-AQAB0AFs4AAHaGmYgAPhgAAMACTY0kYclfKAAMXuSAAmhg4CD2NIAL4Aeg5XJ53wAsuAoAALCUwADUMH4MrlpgVP3iUpZ0mukputxAIJg7FAkFgXMIIFu8CQqEwOFh0hxvl89ugMCtIOpUHwUN+xE+31+AOBGMhTuk5IAViBwRLrnREBgQVAuMhVRggyAkCAmOCPiTYfB8TAoOgsAjOFqSyG8OHfmbyJKgA)

Comment: Ooh this is interesting, Give me a hot second to work threw and actually understand what is going on here, But thanks for the Correct Approach type answer. I especially appreciate these types of answers as I am still learning. One small thing to note is I dont actually use dates I know bad, But the Range picker outputs Json that I parse into string, And work with it from there so I have to actually work with string values which is super annoying but it is what it is, I will adabt this a little bit, as i wont be able to utilize the date sub methods

Comment: Sure, no worries! Your approach is not **wrong** per se, but using good practices from the start can make your source code a lot less cluttered and more readable. Also, as your `takenDates` variable in your function is actually re-initialized at the start of the function, there is actually no need to clear the arrays. They will be empty everytime you start the function.

Comment: The issue is with the snippet I end up changing alot as im working in angular, And the question doesn't look the same as the initial code.. I just tried to make u a stack blitz but its not recreating the issue it actually works there so now im even more lost